# Basis for JNF and matrix relationship for this basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Suppose we are given
$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
-4&4&0\\
-2&1&2
\end{pmatrix}$

Its JNF is
$\mathbf J = \begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}$

I don't understand the following statement

> If we are in the basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ wrt which $\mathbf A$ is in JNF, then the matrix tells us: $\mathbf A e_1 = 2e_1, \mathbf A e_2 =
> 2e_2 + e_1, \mathbf Ae_3 = 2e_3.$

I understand that if $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ is the standard basis then this is true. But it is not necessary that in the standard bases $\mathbf A$ looks like $\mathbf J,$ so why the matrix tells as that?

Comment: I understand that $A$ is the linear application, not the matrix in one particular basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $A$ as information of a change of basis then this can be described as
$$a_1=-4e_2-2e_3,$$
$$a_2=e_1+4e_2+e_3,$$
$$a_3=2e_3.$$
after the calculation of the eigen-vectors and the generalized ones of $A$ you get three vectors
$$v_1=-e_1-2e_2,$$
$$v_2=e_1+2e_2+e_3,$$
$$v_3=e_2,$$
which form a matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS=J$.

Then by solving for $e_1,e_2,e_3$ and subbing
you are going to get
$$a_1=2v_1,$$
$$a_2=v_1+2v_2,$$
$$a_3=2v_2.$$

Comment: take a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordandecomposition+%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-4%2C4%2C0%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C2%7D%7D